# How to read Sitecore Datasource in a sublayout

Tags: c#, sitecore

I have a sub-layout which has a datasource pointing to the data needed for that sublayout to render and I am reading that in fine via

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(this.DataSource)
```

However one of the fields for this data is itself a datasource allowing the editor to set the location of where news items reside.

So they first add the sublayout and set its datasource which defined the details of the rendered panel: title, icons, colours etc but equally a field is held to set the source of where the articles are kept - this way the sublayout can be used multiple times on page but each set to a different content node.

I therefore need my .cs to obtain the value of this "datasource field" so I can then iterate through each of the news items in that defined location to render links to the articles.

To confirm, that field is a DATASOURCE type - hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target field is a **Datasource** field type, please note that it stores the target item by path and not GUID.

Assuming the name of the field is "Notification Location" you'd simply access the target item via the Sitecore API:

```
// your existing code
Item dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(this.DataSource);

// new code
Item selectedNotificationLocationItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dataSource["Notification Location"])
```

Comment: HI, yes I can see the item shows a path - when I write out: output.Text(this.DataSource) I see a GUID which is the initial datasource to the template holding the fields, if I point this to be:

var dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(this.DataSource);
output.Text = "Source: " + Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dataSource["Notification Location"]);

I get nothing written out only the word: Source. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Is the "Notification Location" field set? Did you publish?

Comment: Hi Yes its published, If I do a test on it being NULL it says it isn't and acts on the conditional but nothing is being written out other than the word: source. Thanks

Comment: You're appending the word "Source" to an `Item` because `GetItem(...)` returns an `Item`. Try something like this: `output.Text = "Source: " + Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dataSource["Notification Location"]).ID.ToString();`

Comment: That seems to have done it Ive now getting the correct GUID for the defined location. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2):

When using sublayouts, consider creating a base class

```
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls;

public class BaseSublayout : System.Web.UI.UserControl {

private Item _dataSource = null;
public Item DataSource {
    get {
        if (_dataSource == null)
            if(Parent is Sublayout)
                _dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(((Sublayout)Parent).DataSource);

        return _dataSource;
    }
}

public BaseSublayout() : base() { }

}
```

and all your sublayouts will inherit from this base class.
   You will have on Datasource property the datasource of the components